# fragment how to pass bundle to viewModel by ViewModelInject

Tags: android

I using hilt to inject everything I want in viewModel, I find hilt support SavedStateHandle through @ViewModelInject, so any bundle data pass to it can be get back if I want.

```
class TestViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val testRepository: TestRepository,
    @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    val testItem = state["test"] ?: "defaultValue"
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: TestViewModel by viewModels() // How to pass bundle to the init viewModel?

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems like the way to use ViewModelFactory to init viewModel with bundle.

```
interface ViewModelAssistedFactory<T : ViewModel> {
    fun create(state: SavedStateHandle): T
}

class TestViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val testRepository: TestRepository
) : ViewModelAssistedFactory<TestViewModel> {
    fun create(handle: SavedStateHandle) {
      return TestViewModel(handle, testRepository)
    }
}

class TestViewModel(
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
    private val testRepository: TestRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    val id = state["test"] ?: "defaultValue"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, that you want in instantiate the ViewModel and pass in a bundle I suspect that [Injecting ViewModel with Dagger Hilt](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/injecting-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-54ca2e433865) article might help.

Scrolling towards the bottom there are 2 example using varying methods to instance a ViewModel and one in particular is passing a Bundle.

This is another good resource: [No more Factory Needed for ViewModel with Dependencies](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/injecting-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-54ca2e433865).

This is what I did, maybe not elegant, but it works well:

```
class dataViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    val stateData: StateData,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {
```

Then, to instance the viewModel you need a module definition:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class StateDataModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideStateData(): StateData {
        return StateData(null, null)
    }
}
```

Then, in classes that use it I set the values and the ViewModel retains the values for all instances and across activities (which was my primary reason to do this).

```
dataViewModel.stateData.[property] = blah
```

Comment: It seems the article not talk about how to pass bundle to viewModel and then get the bundle value out through SavedStateHandle.

Comment: I think what you want to do is the same as I did and use cor injection with Bind or Provides.

What confused me the most about the whole HILT and ViewModel, and perhaps you understand the pattern; Basically, the ViewModel's instance is NOT re-constituted, only data classes passed into the ctor are.  This messed me up until I figured out what was going on because I expected the data to be there but in fact only the classes passed are.

In the end, what I did was to pass a container class with a null and then populated the value (then it worked).

I'll edited and demonstrate.